# Google Maps apikey http referrer wildcard TLD

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to use a wildcard for the tld in an http referrer restriction on a google maps api-key?

For example, my referrers are:

- www.example.com/test
- www.example.de/test

It works if I don't use a wildcard for the tld in the api-key restrictions:

- *.example.com/*
- *.example.de/*

It doesn't **NOT** work if I use a wildcard for the tld:

- *.example.*/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the wildcard for TLD is not supported at the moment. There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to improve documentation regarding HTTP referrers:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79474210

Another related feature request where discussed support for wildcards in referrers restrictions is

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80147896

Feel free to star these feature requests to add your vote and subscribe to further notifications from Google.